# Ignore DATETIME parameter in where clause

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008-r2

I have some preset date parameters ('last week', 'two weeks ago', etc) in SSRS.  I want to also have an 'All' parameter that would ignore the

```
and createdon bewtween @FromDate and @ToDate
```

in the where clause and return everything regardless of date.

I've tried to build up some dynamic SQL but the overall query is quite large with many unions and became a mess unto itself. Is there a way to build a case statement here to simplify what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Just add an "OR @All = 1" or whatever you are using to indicate that you want all rows.

Comment: Try to avoid using 'between' with datetime, because you easily create bugs where you leave out any rows from the last day (= @ToDate) that has time in it, e.g. != '00:00'

Comment: @SeanLange, thanks so much, so easy yet escaped me, thanks for the quick response.  if you add it as an answer I'll vote it.

Comment: @JamesZ, true, my example is a simplified version of my where clause, I actually use `dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,datefield),0)` to strip the time off.  my specific one also does a UTC conversion so there's more going on.

Comment: @mrbungle thanks. I don't really care about points so I don't feel the need to post it again as an answer just to get a few points. If the points meant anything or could be traded for something useful I might. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to SeanLange's suggestion that is more extensible, you can just do this:

`AND createdon BETWEEN ISNULL(@FromDate, createdon) AND ISNULL(@ToDate, createdon)`

Then to ignore one or both of these parameters, simply pass `NULL` in. The comparison between `createdon` and itself always succeeds, so the clause is always true.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Today was the first day I've been able to test your solution and verified that it works as well.  The way my report is designed I have to go with SeanLange's suggestion.  Thanks again.